# Break long lines of python code programmatically

Tags: python, autoformatting

What is a/the way to auto-format an existing (potentially large) Python codebase to conform to a given max line length?

Autoformatters like [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), [yapf](https://pypi.org/project/yapf/) and [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/) do change too much as they also change other things.

Comment: Did you try configuring your autoformatter to ignore everything except the line length check?

Comment: Why don't you want to just use black? if they change other things it means that those things were not properly formatted/well written, there is not reason to not use it, it's a standard and you can set a custom line length if you want to

Comment: @rdas May not be possible to make the config of the formatter match the current coding style, as the coding style may not be consistent.

Comment: @Axeltherabbit What is considered properly formatted is usually very debatable, let's assume for the sake of the exercise/question that we'd like to change only line length as other standards could not be agreed on

Comment: That's why there is the pep8 and black, so you can avoid any debate

Comment: @Axeltherabbit thank you for your contribution, this is unfortunately not helpful to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a thing that can be easily solved using an `.editorconfig` file. I don't know what IDE/Code editor you use, but from my experience, pyCharm supports it very well. The config should look something like this:

```
root = true

[*.py]
max_line_length = 88
```

For more info, check https://editorconfig.org/.

Comment: I also thought about that, but wouldn't that require to open all files (possibly many) with the IDE once, so it can apply the changes?

Comment: You can use pyCharm for this, even if it's a one time thing. You have the option to reformat the code in the scope of the whole project.